# Maui class library: Partial Method issue

Tags: c#, maui, partial-classes, partial-methods

In the MAUI class library, within the platform-specific code, I have the following class:

```
public partial class Connector
{
    internal partial void ReadData(string command, Action<string, string> readCallback)
    {

    }
    internal partial void WriteData(string command, Action<string, string> readCallback);    
}
```

Outside platforms folder I have the following class:

```
public partial class Connector
  {
      internal partial void ReadData(string command, Action<string, string> readCallback);

      internal partial void WriteData(string command, Action<string, string> readCallback)
      {

      }
  }
```

The provided code functions correctly when implemented in a MAUI app. However, when incorporated into a MAUI library, an issue arises: the compiler reports an error stating that the partial method "ReadData" must have an implementation, and there is no definition found for the "WriteData" method. WHY?

error:

> Error CS0759 No defining declaration found for implementing
> declaration of partial method 'Connector.WriteData(string,
> Action<string, string>)'.
>
> Error CS8795 Partial method 'Connector.ReadData(string, Action<string,
> string>)' must have an implementation part because it has
> accessibility modifiers.

Some articles recommend against employing partial methods in cross-platform libraries without mentioning the reason. Refer to the following resources for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/992380/partial-classes-and-methods-dont-support-c-9-featu

[Maui class library: Partial Method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851009/maui-class-library-partial-method-issue)

Before you call it an insufficient information, I recommend you create a MAUI library/App and simply copy-paste my code. It should not take a maximum of 5 minutes.

Comment: Please show the errors you see and show where you've defined those different parts of the class. Since you've marked the methods as `internal`, they're not visible outside of the assembly they're defined in: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal Also, the different parts of the class cannot be in different assemblies, AFAIK.

Comment: @Julian, the identical code, without altering a single space, functions properly in the MAUI app. However, it fails to work even when I declare the methods above as public. And they are not different assembly.

Comment: That's not sufficient information. Please show the structure of the library project.

Comment: @Julian, my library doesn't contain anything else. I recommend you create a MAUI library and simply copy-paste my code. It should take a maximum of 2 minutes

Comment: @Julian, Also the MAUI app I'm referring to doesn't include anything else besides the code I've shared. MAUI app is compiling but MAUI lib doesn't.

Comment: Please show the error message you see as well as the project structure. Your question doesn't include enough details.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error CS0759 No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'Connector.WriteData(string, Action<string, string>)'.
Error CS8795 Partial method 'Connector.ReadData(string, Action<string, string>)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.

Comment: Please add this information to the question.

Comment: @julian, I would have appreciated it if you had requested my question to be closed after attempting the code I shared. The code is adequate for comprehending the question. It is unrelated to access modifiers, and I won't attempt to use "internal" outside of the assembly unless the assembly is marked as "InternalVisibleTo."

Comment: The issue is you have methods in your library that don't have platform implementations in all of the supported platforms

Comment: @slashshogdhe Like Liyun Zhang's answer implies, the code you shared doesn't suffice to reproduce the issue, because it doesn't show the namespaces of your partial classes. Liyun's answer probably is correct and should solve your issue, however, this cannot be said with 100% certainty unless you update the code to include all necessary details, which includes the namespace. As such, my request to close the question until all necessary details to reproduce the issue are included is justified. Did you manage to solve the issue in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem. It was caused by the different namespace for the partial class. The official document about [Implementing the API per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0) said:

> Platform implementations must be in the same namespace and same class that the cross-platform API was defined in.

But when you create a class in the Platforms folder, its default namespace is `YourProjectName.Platforms.PlatformName`. Please make the partial classes's namespace in the platforms folder is same as it in the share project.